# Remove lines during boot tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

How i can remove lines during boot tableView when i start my App?
I tryed add **activityIndicator**, but he no help me.

May be I somehow incorrectly set up **UIView** or need to use something else?

May be need code **activityIndicator**:

```
private func setLoadingScreen() {

    let width: CGFloat = 30
    let height: CGFloat = 30
    let x = (self.tableView.frame.width / 2) - (width / 2)
    let y = (self.tableView.frame.height / 2) - (height / 2) - (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)!
    loadingView.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)

    self.activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .gray
    self.activityIndicator.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
    self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()

    loadingView.addSubview(self.activityIndicator)

    self.tableView.addSubview(self.loadingView)

}

private func removeLoadingScreen() {

    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()

}
```

[image: AI]

Comment: Set the separatorStyle of the tableview to UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone.

Comment: and as I had not thought about it)) thanks:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution will be to set the value of the `separatorStyle` property defined by `UITableView` to  `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone` before loading.

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = .none
```

After the loading is done you can set it back to `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine`

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = .singleLine
```

[Apple Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcellseparatorstyle?language=objc)

Answer (score 1):

I like to create an extension on `UITableView` for this:

```
public extension UITableView {
    /**
    Hides the separators which display when the table view is empty.
     */
    func hideSeparators() {
        guard tableFooterView == nil else { return }
        tableFooterView = UIView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set empty `UITableView` footer. In this case you don't have to switch back separatorStyle.

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

or set the `UITableView` separater style to `.none`

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = .none
```